# Get a JSON object in python

Tags: python, json, types

Usually my webservice built with Bottle return JSON files, which works fine. But, I've an exception that need to call a local function.

Here is what I tried to do:

```
import json
def getData():
    return json.dumps({'data': someData })

def function():
    try:
        # Fail
    except:
        print getData()
        print type(getData())
        json.load(getData())
```

So it prints:

```
{"data": "myData"}
<type 'str'>
[...]
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

So `json.dumps` gives me a string. How can I use it as JSON ?

Comment: First, where is your `return` in front of `json`?

Comment: Sorry, I rewrite it to make it simple. I've forgot the `return`.

Comment: `someData` is already a `dict()` you just access `someData` ... at least it should be. If it's a string then you need to call `json.load()` on it

Comment: And assign it to a variable :)

Comment: @Cfreak It seems to be a `dict` because of the `{ ... }`, but it's actually a string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`json.load` loads JSON from a file object.

`json.loads` loads from a string. This is what you want.

Comment: I knew there was a simple answer. Thank you.

Comment: Technically it's a file-like object (has read() method), so this will work: `json.load(StringIO('["streaming API"]'))`

Answer (score 2):

Use `json.loads` instead of `json.load`. As per the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html).